# Can anybody explain the meaning of "from things to experiences" in this context?

Tags: meaning

> "Global travel continues to be an attractive investment area," Sandra
>   Horbach, cohead of Carlyle Group's US buyout team, told Business
>   Insider. "Consumers are increasingly shifting their spending **from
>   things to experiences**. Travel will also benefit from rising
>   discretionary incomes in many emerging markets.

source: "[Wall Street's big investors are piling into tourism](http://www.businessinsider.com/private-equity-firms-piling-into-tourism-investment-2016-7),"
 by Rachel Butt, *Business Insider*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portion you've made bold is only a part of the phrase. The phrase is:

> shifting **X** from **Y** to **Z**

Which means they are gradually changing **X** (what they spend money on) from **Y** (things – material possessions, souvenirs, etc.) to **Z** (experiences – making memories, having fun, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

In the past, people mostly bought *things*, meaning they bought objects, like cars, paintings, clothes, etc.

Now, they spend more money on *experiences*, like holidays. A holiday is not a "thing" that you can put in your home, but it is an "experience", something that creates a memory.

Basically you could rephrase the sentence to

> Consumers are increasingly shifting their spending from tangible objects they can hold in their hands to more abstract things that they can experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could spend your "fun money" on a thing, such as a gadget, piece of art, nice furniture, jewelry etc. Or you could spend it on an interesting experience, such as staying in a very special hotel, or riding in a helicopter over a scenic location, or attending a cookery lesson with a renowned chef.

Some people feel that experiences are ephemeral and "things" are longer lasting, but the Business Insider claims that in general there is a shift in spending towards the experiences.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite literal. When you buy a new TV you're buying something tangible, an actual thing you can see, touch, etc. When you go on a trip, it's the experience you're paying for, but the trip itself is not something you can hold in your hand or put in your pocket.

A more appropriate term would be "from goods to services", "goods" meaning actual tangible things, as opposed to "services", someone doing something for you, like taking you to Thailand and getting you a place to sleep, with food included, etc.